# if command not working login form C# visual studio

Tags: c#

I created a simple login program in C# with Access database, but if function didn't work when i run the program. Function is skipped and if login is right message appear

> Username or Password is incorrect

I'm not professional, just learning and trying to make any simple software.

This is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data 
Source=D:\Backup\Desktop\zzzzzzzzzzz\userdata.accdb;
Persist Security Info=False;";
    }

    private void userdataBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, 
EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.userdataBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.userdataDataSet);

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.userdataTableAdapter.Fill(this.userdataDataSet.userdata);
        txt_login.Text = "";
        txt_pword.Text = "";
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            check.Text = "Database Connected";
            con.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error" + ex);
        }

    }

    private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandText = "select * from userdata where login='" + 
txt_login + "'and pword='" + txt_pword + "'";
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        int count = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            count = count +1;
        }
        if (count==1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Login successfull");
        }
        else if (count>1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrect");
        }

        con.Close();
    }

    private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does it "not work"?  What do you mean it is "skipped"?  When the code executes, it performs exactly the logic that's written.  When you step through the code in your debugger, where specifically does an unexpected result first occur?  What are the relevant variable values when that happens?  What specifically were you expecting to happen on that exact operation?  Why?

Comment: What is `txt_login` and `txt_pword`? In one place you access the property `Text` of them, in other you use as if they are the text themselves.

Comment: thnx for reply bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sql statement has txt_login, it should be txt_login.Text. Similarly txt_pword should be txt_pword.Text.

*Pls Note: My answer is based on the code snip you have posted*

Comment: thnx bro it worked now i have mistake i didn't write .text in the end of both text boxes in code thnx again and thnx to all also for cooperate if any other problem i hope you'll be support me as now... thnx again to all specially @jayce

Answer (score 0):

assuming that `txt_login` and `txt_pword` are `TextBox`es on your form, you need to use their `Text` property. Also if all you care about is the count, then do that directly in SQL and you don't need a loop:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM userdata WHERE login='" +
                      txt_login.Text + "' AND pword='" + txt_pword.Text + "'";
```

But your query is susptible to SQL injection attacks, so learn how to use [parameterized query](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access).